# mysql asp.net unknown fail

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am trying to create a survey project. I opened a new ASP.NET Empty Web Application. I am using XAMMP to be able to use MySQL. Here are the items I added to my project:
References:

```
MySql.Data 
MySql.Data.Entity 
MySql.Data.Entity.EF6
```

Libraries:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient 
MySql.Data
```

This is GUI: [enter link description here][1]

DB name:deneme2
Table name: dene
Columns: ID(int-primary key-auto increment),cevap(text-utf8_turkish_ci)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = "Server=localhost; Database=deneme2; uid=root; Password=;";
            MySqlConnection baglanti = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            baglanti.Open();

            string a = baglanti.ConnectionTimeout.ToString();
            try
            {

                Label2.Text = a;
                MySqlCommand komut_kayit1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO dene (cevap) VALUES ('" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem + "'");
                komut_kayit1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                baglanti.Close();

                Label2.Text = "Başarılı.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Label1.Text = "Başarısız.";
                Label3.Text = Convert.ToString(ex);
            }
        }

Here is the error message that I got from label3
System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open. at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at soru.Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\BM499\3. Hafta\11. GÜN\soru\soru\Default.aspx.cs:line 31
```

When I go to Line 31, there is only brackets but I checked all of my brackets and there should be a fail. They are all normal.

```
komut_kayit1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I comment it with //, I can see Başarılı(Success) text in Label2. I think the problem is in

```
MySqlCommand komut_kayit1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO dene (cevap) VALUES ('" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem + "'");
```

Seems normal to me. What should I do?

```
MySqlCommand komut_kayit1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO dene (cevap) VALUES ('" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem + "')",baglanti);
```

My problem is solved. I forgot two brackets and "baglanti". I'm going to learn overloading after this project. Thanks for your advice. 
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0x8y.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a simple error in your mysqlcommand sintax.
Your sqlcommand requires 2 parameter to make the query :
COMMAND STATEMENT => fine you pass it 
CONNECTIONSTRING => baglanti which is not passed yet

**short form**

```
MySqlCommand komut_kayit1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO dene (cevap) VALUES ('" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem + "'",baglanti);
```

**long form**

```
MySqlCommand komut_kayit1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO dene (cevap) VALUES ('" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem + "'");
komut_kayait1.Connection=baglanti;
```

then you can call ExeceuteNonQuery.

Take a look to the overload into the methods New MysqlCommand :)

I hope it help you

Another stuff your method is wid open to sqlinjection.I suggest you to never use this concatanations is better if you use a parameter instead a simple string.